# Auto Layout views inoperable in iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I'm using Auto Layout for an iPhone app to place a button footer bar at the bottom of the screen on both 3.5" and 4" iPhones. The bar is a UIView containing two UIButtons and a UIImageView.

I have a Vertical Space Constraint pinning the bottom space to the superview.

(Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to Superview)

It has an Equal relationship. Constant is 60, Standard is NO, Priority is 1000, and Placeholder is NO.

In iOS 7 it works exactly as expected. In iOS 6, it does not. The bar is not a consistent distance from the bottom when I switch between that view controller and its neighbors, and the buttons frequently do not work (they don't even highlight when I tap them). This is all in the simulator, I haven't tried hardware yet. The app is a legacy app, so all of the layout work is in xib files, not storyboards.

Do I need to do something different in iOS 6 to get Auto Layout to work? From what I read, it should be fully compatible with 6 & 7.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information is needed to really get to the heart of the matter.  Specifically how auto layout is being used to attach the bar to the bottom.

One thing that gets me over and over though, is remembering to set the translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints property to false on view(s) that utilize constraints.

Be sure to check the log output while debugging as that will indicate if you have any ambiguous or unsatisfiable constraints.  At design time, XCode 4 IB will attempt to add any constraints that you are missing for you.  XCode 5 IB will only tell you what you are missing and then at runtime try to add any missing constraints if it can.